# DRY react-router's getComponent functions

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, code-splitting

Routing with react-router, redux and redux-saga entails a lot of repeated code, just have a look [here](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/blob/master/app/routes.js#L20-L41). 21 lines for a single route. In my app I have dozens of routes, so it is very important to DRY it out somehow. Otherwise this file `routes.js` will be a mess with 1000+ lines.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I came to [this](https://github.com/yantakus/webpack-example/blob/master/app/routes.js). It works fine and helps to make one route declaration just 4 lines for simple routes and 8 for those using sagas and childRoutes.